# Creating New Invoice Line if Item Count is Non-Zero

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, invoice

I'm attempting to create a Google Sheet that automatically adds lines to an invoice based on data inputted into a table. This is for a vending machine, so when filling, I would like to add a number to the Units Sold column on the "Products" sheet. To send the invoice, I would like each item with a non-zero Units Sold to be added to the more aesthetically pleasing "Invoice" sheet.

Here is a link to the Sheet I have started tinkering with: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_VBPxOVIfnHYqqrZHxaXdqW-Q5JcPSYS4fu5VeLYcho/edit?usp=sharing

Is this idea possible using scripts in Google Sheets?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. While links to external content might be helpful, questions on this site should be self contained. Considering this, please describe all the relevant parts of your spreadsheet directly in the question body as well add some some sample input and the corresponding output data. It does't matter how amateur / begimner your are, on questions about writing code you should show what you have tried. Ref. [ask]. If you need something to start with, start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `I'm attempting to create a Google Sheet that automatically adds lines to an invoice based on data inputted into a table. This is for a vending machine, so when filling, I would like to add a number to the Units Sold column on the "Products" sheet. To send the invoice, I would like each item with a non-zero Units Sold to be added to the more aesthetically pleasing "Invoice" sheet.`. Can I ask you about the detal of the current issue of your script and your goal?

Comment: BTW, you show the "Sub-total "of the products sold = $126; the actual sum = $148. Agree?

Comment: Hi. May I respectfully suggest that you may be overcomplicating the solution to this scenario. Rather than creating script to "build" the entire invoice, I suggest using a `query`  to populate the rows of the invoice (based on the "Units Sold" column on "Products") and then a simple script to hide/unhide any blank rows. This allows you to manage/keep your Invoice footer (complete with formatting) without having to reproduce it in a script. @Rubén has asked that you supply more information in the body of your question. When you've done this, I would be happy to post an answer.